# How can I convert a pandas Period into a timestamp or datetime object?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date stored as a Pandas Period object:

```
date1 = Period(1989, 'Y')
```

I want to compare it with a datetime object, which is:

```
date2 = datetime.strftime('1988-09-09', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I hope I can do a subtraction like below:

```
diff = date2 - date1
```

In order to do that, I need to convert the Period into a datetime object. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

- By using [`pandas.Period.to_timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html)

  - Use the `freq` parameter to specify start or end
- `date2 = datetime.strftime('1988-09-09', '%Y-%m-%d')` causes a `TypeError`

  - Use `date2 = pd.to_datetime('1988-09-09')` to get a datetime format

```py
import pandas as pd

date1 = pd.Period(1989, 'Y')

date1_ts = date1.to_timestamp()

print(date1_ts)
[out]:
Timestamp('1989-01-01 00:00:00')

# create date2 as a datetime, not a string
date2 = pd.to_datetime('1988-09-09')

# take the difference
diff = date2 - date1_ts

print(diff)
[out]: 
Timedelta('-114 days +00:00:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas import DataFrame, Period

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = {'Year': [Period(1989, 'Y')]}

    df = DataFrame(data,
                   columns=['Year'])

    date2 = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d').split('-')[0]
    date1 = df['Year'].values[0].year
    diff = int(date2) - date1
    print(diff)
```

`date2 = datetime.strftime('1988-09-09', '%Y-%m-%d')` gave error, therefore I replaced with

```
date2 = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d').split('-')[0]
```

Output:

```
31
```